# findViewbyID with dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, findviewbyid

I am attempting to extract a user input in a specific dialog box.
However, when I attempt to use findViewbyID and I put in

```
final EditText ExceedingLimitInput = (EditText)dialog.findViewbyId(R.id.ExceedingLimitInput);
```

Android Studio says that dialog is not defined. I am not quite sure what I am supposed to do here.

I have dug through some of the questions relating to this, however most of them related only to Fragment usage, while I am not using any fragments. Maybe I am extending the wrong class?

Can someone please show why dialog is not being defined, and how I can fix it?

Here is my code for reference:

Settings Menu (Main Class)

```
package com.example.denny.protoype2;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class SettingsMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_menu);
        //Exceeding Limit Dialog
        final Button ExceedingLimitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ExceedingLimitButton);
        ExceedingLimitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog ExceedingLimitDialog = new Dialog(SettingsMenu.this);
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setTitle("Exceeding Limit Dialog");
                ExceedingLimitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.exceeding_limit_dialog);
                ExceedingLimitDialog.show();

                final EditText ExceedingLimitInput = (EditText)dialog.findViewbyId(R.id.ExceedingLimitInput);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, you're looking for something in the dialog which you have never defined, you defined ExceedingLimitDialog so replace dialog with ExceedingLimitDialog

Comment: Yeah, lol. I was screwing myself over with that stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should inflate your view

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.exceeding_limit_dialog, null);
```

Then set it to your dialog

```
ExceedingLimitDialog.setContentView(view);
```

And finally you can find your EditText

```
final EditText ExceedingLimitInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ExceedingLimitInput);
```

Comment: May be the problem is small 'b' in findViewById

Comment: Wow... I am such a dweeb :/

Answer (score 5):

do like

```
 final EditText ExceedingLimitInput = (EditText)ExceedingLimitDialog.findViewbyId(R.id.ExceedingLimitInput);
```

**dailog ==ExceedingLimitDialog** in your case